# RuntimeException: Can't create directory

Tags: php, zend-framework, directory, ubuntu, runtime

my website https://roofmegastore.co.uk/ is coming up with this error.

```
    1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException): Directory "/var/www/html/magento/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_GB" cannot be created Warning!mkdir(): Permission denied

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException): Directory "/var/www/html/magento/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_GB" cannot be created Warning!mkdir(): Permission denied
#0 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php(199): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->mkdirRecursive('/var/www/html/m...', 511)
#1 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Directory/Write.php(89): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->createDirectory('/var/www/html/m...', 511)
#2 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Directory/Write.php(247): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Write->create('frontend/Smartw...')
#3 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Directory/Write.php(264): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Write->openFile('frontend/Smartw...', 'w+')
#4 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-require-js/Model/FileManager.php(135): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Write->writeFile('frontend/Smartw...', '(function(requi...')
#5 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-require-js/Model/FileManager.php(63): Magento\RequireJs\Model\FileManager->ensureSourceFile('frontend/Smartw...')
#6 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-require-js/Block/Html/Head/Config.php(126): Magento\RequireJs\Model\FileManager->createRequireJsConfigAsset()
#7 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(272): Magento\RequireJs\Block\Html\Head\Config->_prepareLayout()
#8 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php(150): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->setLayout(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor))
#9 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php(80): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#10 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(343): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#11 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(129): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements()
#12 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php(55): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#13 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#14 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(253): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#15 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(875): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build()
#16 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-cms/Helper/Page.php(171): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock('page_content_he...')
#17 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-cms/Controller/Index/Index.php(43): Magento\Cms\Helper\Page->prepareResultPage(Object(Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), 'porto_home_21')
#18 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index->execute()
#19 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#21 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 /var/www/html/magento/generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#23 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#26 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#31 /var/www/html/magento/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#32 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#33 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(257): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#34 /var/www/html/magento/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#35 {main}
```

I've given it access and tried to re-upgrade it but nothing seems to be working for, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is permission is not set correctly. If you face this type of error then login from SSH and from Magento root directiry run below command.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure to assign the proper permissions to your user. As you can see on the error line it is an permissions problem:

```
..porto/en_GB" cannot be created Warning!mkdir(): Permission denied
```

As soon as you assigned the right permissions to create directories this should be solved.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I use Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

**This is a permission issue.**

**Run below command step by step in root directory:**

> sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/
>
> sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> sudo rm -rf var/cache/* var/generation/*
>
> sudo php bin/magento cache:flush

Let me know if any issue.

Hope it help!